# What else might be stopping manifest.json from being served?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

The problem I am having seems fairly common though does not seem to be resolved by existing answers.

I am running an MVC app through an azure web app. When I publish the site and run it I get the following error regarding the manifest.json file:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Most existing answers point to the mime mapping, however to the web.config I have added the following lines inside the existing `system.webServer` block:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".json" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

This has not worked.

Things I have checked:

1. manifest.json exists in `/js/` as does test.json I can open test.json
2. the file exists under the same domain as the file requesting it

This is the manifest.json file:

```
{
  "name": "MidexPRO",
  "short_name": "MidexPRO",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/favicons/android-chrome-36x36.png",
      "sizes": "36x36",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/favicons/android-chrome-48x48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/favicons/android-chrome-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/favicons/android-chrome-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/favicons/android-chrome-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/favicons/android-chrome-256x256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/favicons/android-chrome-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/favicons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "theme_color": "#57baa3",
  "background_color": "#57baa3",
  "start_url": "/app.htm",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

This is the test.json file:

```
{
  "a": 1
}
```

**UPDATE...**
I'm still finding myself stuck on this and no further luck on google. Just a hope that a fresh look at the question may prompt some responses!